Why does my model still look blocky even after I use Shade Smooth to smooth it out?
I'm learning to make high-poly models, and I ran into an issue. When I use Shade Smooth+Subdivision Surface, the result still looks blocky (like on the left) instead of smooth like I expected (on the right).

If I add three Subdivision Surface iterations, the model looks smooth and the result is fine for me. But as far as I know, three iterations generate way too much geometry. Is this normal, or is there a more optimized way to get the same result?

Maybe the blocky smoothing issue is related to how I created this object and the modifiers I used, so I'll explain the process and share the file below for better understanding.

I started with a plane, added a few loop cuts, and shaped it into a
concave form.
Then I applied the Solidify modifier to give the plane
some thickness.
After that, I tried using the Bevel and Subdivision
Surface modifiers, but Bevel gave me weird results. So, I ended up
adding supporting edges manually using Ctrl+B to achieve the current
shape.

Now I have a few questions:

Could the blocky smoothing be caused by the modeling process itself?
Or is it more about how smoothing is applied?

I’m aware of tools like Bevel Weight and Edge Crease, but I’m not sure how to use them correctly in this case.
I’ve also noticed similar blocky smoothing on other low-geometry objects, like the sphere shown below.

In many 3D tutorials I’ve watched, I see similar blocky objects, but the creators never comment on it and just move on. This leaves me confused, and I’d really like to understand.
Thanks in advance for your answers! I hope I managed to explain my problem clearly and can get detailed feedback.
I used Blender version 4.0. Auto Smooth was enabled on the object. 
Blender file here

Shade smooth smoothens the shade, not the model.

You could have "duplicated" vertices or edges there. (Result of canceled extrusions, Misplaced loopcuts, etc). Or split edges. You can in edit mode select all (a) and merge (m) by distance to remove the duplications. Might improve the results of subdivision. You might have inner faces (faces that were extruded inside the volume and you can't really see, but affect the subdivision, must look with X-ray and try to see if there are faces inside).

Bevels must be made with an "edge" selected for better result. (And will be affected by duplications and splits)

@DanielMöller Of course, I applied Bevel to edges only, not the entire selected geometry.
So, if 'Shade Smooth smoothens the shade, not the model,' does it mean that the blocky edges are normal? Is this how it’s supposed to be, or is there something else causing it?

@DanielMöller I already checked everything you mentioned before posting this. The model is included, so you can take a look.
